# need help setting up reddit oauth with nodejs

Tags: node.js, oauth, reddit

I've been struggling with this for a couple days now and the Reddit API documentation has not provided me with the insight i need to get oauth access using node. I registered my application with Reddit and entered 'http://localhost:3000/authorize' as my redirect_ URL since this is for testing. Reddit then provided me with a consumer key and secret.
I cannot figure out where to go from here though. As far as i can tell, i have to somehow redirect the browser to 'https://ssl.reddit.com/api/v1/authorize' and provide my consumer_key and secret. The user can then login, and be redirected back to my demo site.
What i need is a small guide or demo that i can study to find out how to set this whole process up using node.

Comment: [Reddit's documentation](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2) is here and should get you started.  The examples are python and PHP, not node, but are short and straightforward.  Auth frameworks like [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) trivialize oauth flows.  I personally like passport a lot.  There doesn't seem to be a Reddit plugin yet, but you should be able to look at any of the other OAuth2 [provider plugins](http://passportjs.org/) for guidance

Comment: Alternatively you can use [Grant](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grant) which supports Reddit. Also there is a lengthy article about OAuth in general and [how to use Grant](https://scotch.io/tutorials/implement-oauth-into-your-express-koa-or-hapi-applications-using-grant)

Answer (score 1):

[Here's the npm module, passport-reddit](https://npmjs.org/package/passport-reddit).